# Modern views on the correspondence of moles

Tags: embryology, histology

In his *[Memoirs](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2981/2981-h/2981-h.htm)*, Casanova wrote:

> In the midst of the dimple which added such a charm to her chin Esther had a little dark mole, garnished with three or four extremely fine hairs. These moles, which we call in Italian ‘neo, nei’, and which are usually an improvement to the prettiest face, when they occur on the face, the neck, the arms, or the hands, are duplicated on the corresponding parts of the body. I concluded, therefore, that Esther had a mole like that on her chin in a certain place which a virtuous girl does not shew [...]
>
> I then explained to her the theory of the correspondence of moles on the various parts of the human body, and to convince her I ended by saying that her governess who had a large mark on her right cheek ought to have one very like it on her left thigh.

Does contemporary biology/medicine support this law? Are there publications on it?

Comment: Law? If you go around looking for moles on women’s thighs you are certainly likely to end up with the law after you. Come on, are you as gullible as the women who fell for Casanova’s nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of [different types of moles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevus) out there, and while there are correlations in locations of [some classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevus_of_Ota) based on their nature, there is nothing like the correspondence described.

There is, however, a long history of attempting to attribute meanings and patterns to moles, however, since essentially random phenomena like this tend to engage our human biases for pattern-making.